# How to add up all numbers from loop

Tags: javascript

I want something  like this but I have no idea how to do this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQfHH.png

```
var number = document.getElementById('x').value;
        var i = 1;
        var sum = 0;
        while(i <= number){
            sum += i;
            i++;
        }
        document.getElementById('html').innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code, as written? What is it doing, or not doing, that's not what you want?

Comment: I want it to add up all numbers from 1 to x, for example if x is 4
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10

Comment: What's this outputting, vs your expected output. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: On screenshot is what i want it to look like

Comment: You're only outputting the sum *after* your loop. If you want a line for each iteration, you'll need to include that *inside* your loop.

Comment: you probably want to convert `number` to, well, a number (it will be a string in your code) before executing this loop. This will likely matter if `number` is 10 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = (n) => new Array(n).fill(0).map((_, k) => k + 1);
const calc = (n) => arr(n).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
const log = (n) => console.log(n, '=>', arr(n).join(' + '), '=', calc(n));

log(3);
log(5);
```

- `new Array(n)` create an array with `n`th elements
- `.fill(0)` fill the array with zeros
- `.map((_, k) => k + 1)` fill the array with integer (`k` is the index of the array, which is zero based)
- `.reduce()` allow to calculate to sum of every element of the array
- `.join()` will concatenate every element of the array to create the `x + y` part

PS: Vincent was quicker but already have redacted my awnser

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to output `number` lines, each with `1+2+... = N`, you could do:

```js
let output = "";
for (n=1; n <= number; n++)
  output += `${
                /* "1+2+...+n" */
                Array(n).fill().map((_,i) => i+1).join("+")
             } = ${
                /* the sum */
                n * (n+1) / 2
             }\n`;
```